# Add preview button on Taxonomy add/edit term form

Tags: 8, entities

As we know that **entity type node** has **preview** button option which can be used during adding or editing of a node, to preview content.

[image]

Same feature is missing in case of **Taxonomy entity**.

If I want to add this feature where should I look into or is there any module available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Preview button added by node module in [NodeForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeForm.php/8.2.x) as `action` in actions method:

```
$element['preview'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#access' => $preview_mode != DRUPAL_DISABLED && ($node->access('create') || $node->access('update')),
      '#value' => t('Preview'),
      '#weight' => 20,
      '#submit' => ['::submitForm', '::preview'],
    ];
```

The `Taxonomy entity` form created by [TermForm.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermForm.php/8.2.x) so i think you should:

1. Extends `TermForm.php` in another Class.
2. Add `actions` method.
3. Create a `preview` method like the node preview method but for the term.
4. Add a route subscriber to tell drupal to load your form not the default.